# R error in unique.default(x) unique() applies only to vectors

Tags: r

I created a dataset  named `state`  from the built-in matrix `state.x77` with two continuous variables (Population and Income) and two factor variables (region and area).

I computed mean income by region using `tapply()`, `by()`, `aggregate()`, and `ave()` to see the format of the returned object.

But the call to `ave()` is giving the error

> Error in unique.default(x) : unique() applies only to vectors

The code is:

```
## Mean income by region
tapply(state$inc, state$region, mean)
# Northeast         South North Central          West 
# 4570.222       4011.938      4611.083      4702.615 

by(state$inc, state$region, mean)
# state$region: Northeast
#
# [1] 4570.222
# [...]

aggregate(state$inc, list(state$region), mean)
#
#         Group.1        x
# 1     Northeast 4570.222
# 2         South 4011.938
# 3 North Central 4611.083
# 4          West 4702.615

ave(state$inc, state$region, mean)
# Error in unique.default(x) : unique() applies only to vectors
```

Why is the error occurring? How can I prevent it?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is a very common mistake, you need to use the named argument `FUN`:

```
ave(state$inc, state$region, FUN = mean)
```

otherwise `mean` will be interpreted as another grouping variable (part of the `...` argument to `ave`.)

Comment: Thank you very much. the error has been prevented. But i also didn't use FUN in tapply(), by(), aggregate() command. then why those didn't occur error?

Comment: It is because inside `ave`'s synopsis (argument list), `FUN` comes **after** `...` so if you do not pass it specifically with `FUN=`, then R will think it is part of the `...` argument and use the default (`mean`) for `FUN`.

Answer (score 1):

You may check whether the R use the correct function, I tried to specify the function just like below example.
`enrichplot::dotplot(kegg)`
That may help you.
ps.I am a beginner of R script.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).