# R Error in unique.default(x) : unique() applies only to vectors when using ddply

Tags: r

I have to get the final data frame using ddply of the package plyr. Here is   the code:

```
POI_instances = ddply(.data = POI_proximity, .variables = c("owner","deviceid","date"), .fun = function(df){data.frame(min_time = min(df$loc_ts),max_time = max(df$loc_ts))})
```

Basically, I am trying to subset the given data frame "POI_proximity" into the final data set "POI_instances" by applying function given in the third argument.

But I am getting the error:

### R Error in unique.default(x) : unique() applies only to vectors

I did tried [already asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16681770/r-error-in-unique-defaultx-unique-applies-only-to-vectors) but didn't get the solution. Any Help Possible?

Comment: Have you tried with `ddply` with `summarize`.  May be `ddply(POI_proximity, .(owner, deviceid, date), summarize, min_time=min(loc_ts), max_time=max(loc_ts))`  not tested without an example

Comment: Here is the complication, I am able to run the code in my local windows machine with Rstudio except when I am trying to run it on the Hetzner server using Linux Centos.

Comment: Did you meant that your code works on some operating system but not others?  I am using `linux mint 17` with `R 3.1.2` It does work fine with `summarize` though.

Comment: Both the codes worked for me.  But, your code is probably not correct as it is giving you the `min` values of the whole `loc_ts` column instead of giving min for each group.

Comment: Yes, one is windows platform in which my code is running, but in the Linux environment it's not.

Comment: Moreover the code inside the function is correct as I am getting the desired result in one environment.

Comment: except platform everything is same in the "version" command.

Comment: Anyway, both codes worked for me.