# How to make contingency table over a list in r

Tags: r, lapply, chi-squared

The main exposure variable is `aff`. I want to get contingency tables for `aff` and all variables in the `varlist`. Then I want to do chi-square test using these contingency tables. My codes are following:

```
name=names(data)
varlist=name[11:40]
models=lapply(varlist, function(x) {
          chisq.test(table(substitute(data$i,list(i = as.name(x))),data$aff))
 })
lapply(models, summary)
```

But I got error

```
Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) : 
  unique() applies only to vectors
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16681770/r-error-in-unique-defaultx-unique-applies-only-to-vectors) would be useful?

Comment: Paste the output of `dput(data)` into your question. At the present state of your question, we cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: Ok, sure, if you want to retain the intermediate tables. Does this mean my answer resolves your question? If so, please "accept" the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're over-complicating things by using `substitute` and such. Without your data, I'll try with `mtcars`, using `cyl` as the exposure variable.

```
data <- mtcars
name <- names(data)
ev <- "cyl"
varlist <- name[ name != ev ]
models <- lapply(varlist, function(nm) {
  chisq.test(table(data[[nm]], data[[ev]]))
})
# Warning messages:
# 1: In chisq.test(table(data[[nm]], data[[ev]])) :
#   Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

(because I'm using a bad example for the test, there are a lot of warnings here; this can be ignored when using `mtcars` because it is really not a good dataset for this test.)

```
summaries <- lapply(models, summary)
str(summaries[1:2])
# List of 2
#  $ : 'summaryDefault' chr [1:9, 1:3] " 1" " 1" " 1" " 1" ...
#   ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#   .. ..$ : chr [1:9] "statistic" "parameter" "p.value" "method" ...
#   .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "Length" "Class" "Mode"
#  $ : 'summaryDefault' chr [1:9, 1:3] " 1" " 1" " 1" " 1" ...
#   ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#   .. ..$ : chr [1:9] "statistic" "parameter" "p.value" "method" ...
#   .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "Length" "Class" "Mode"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is very illuminating, but I revise ur codes a little bit. ------------------------------------- lapply(varlist, function(nm) {
     table(registry[[nm]], registry[[ev]])
})
    lapply(models,chisq.test)

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your data is like `mtcars`, where `vs`, `am`, `gear`, and `carb` are categorical variables, you can create a function like so:

```
df_list_f <- function(x) chisq.test(table(df2$cyl, x))
df2 <- mtcars[,8:11] # df2 contains the columns vs, am, gear and carb
lapply(df2, df_list_f)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I can't follow your code. What's x? df2$cyl?

Comment: `df2` is your `data`. `cyl` is your `aff`. I am just demonstrating a procedure that you can replicate. Provide your data and we can taylor this solution to it.