# Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) : unique() applies only to vectors by using with(data_frame, table(year, country))

Tags: r, dataframe

My data looks like this:

| year | country |
| --- | --- |
| 1990 | USA |
| 1991 | USA |
| 1991 | UK |
| 1990 | UK |
| 1991 | USA |
| 1991 | UK |
| 1992 | USA |
| 1992 | UK |
| 1992 | UK |

I am trying to execute the following row of the code

`Freq <- data.frame(with(data_frame, table(year, country)))`

to get the frequencies of each country in my data set in every year that looks like this.

| year | country | frequency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1990 | USA | 1 |
| 1991 | USA | 2 |
| 1992 | USA | 1 |
| 1990 | UK | 1 |
| 1991 | UK | 2 |
| 1992 | UK | 2 |

Until recently, the code worked okay and this is exactly what I had as an output.
Today I installed an RSelenium package and after that by executing the row above I get the error

> Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) :
> unique() applies only to vectors

I don't know if Selenium has something to do with it. Why can this happen, and how can I fix this? Any tips will be very appreciated.

I already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16681770/r-error-in-unique-defaultx-unique-applies-only-to-vectors) question, but unfortunately, it was of no use for me.

P.S.: this is my first question here, sorry, if it's a little crooked.

Comment: Can you please make your data reproducible? See tips on how here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example. PS. With the data provided in akrun answer your code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

An option with `count`

```
library(dplyr)
count(df1, year, country)
```

-output

```
year country n
1 1990      UK 1
2 1990     USA 1
3 1991      UK 2
4 1991     USA 2
5 1992      UK 2
6 1992     USA 1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(year = c(1990L, 1991L, 1991L, 1990L, 1991L, 1991L, 
1992L, 1992L, 1992L), country = c("USA", "USA", "UK", "UK", "USA", 
"UK", "USA", "UK", "UK")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```